# MYSQLI UPDATE prepared statement not updating my table

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a problem with my PHP updating script. I'm using prepared statements with mysqli, but the code isn't working although I see no error.

```
$c=mysqli_connect('localhost','client','','bdd');
if (!$c) {    
    echo 'Erreur de connexion a la base de donnees';
} else {    
   if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
     $faite=1;        
     for($i=0;$i<sizeof($idg);$i++){
        $var=$idg[$i]; 
        $update="UPDATE  graissage SET   faite= ? where  id=?";
        echo $update;
        $stmt2= mysqli_prepare($c, $update);
        echo mysqli_error($c);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt2, "is", $faite,$var);
        echo mysqli_error($c);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt2);
        echo mysqli_error($c);
    }
}}
```

Comment: Are you bind params the wrong way around? I.e. string _then_ int?

Comment: the type of variables is same as in the database @Jon

Comment: You're trying to tell me that `faite` is an `int` and `id` is a string?

Comment: yes exactly ! @Jon

Comment: I don't believe that I'm afraid.

Comment: even if i change id to integer in the table and bind it as integer is still not working

Comment: I don't get it why @Jon

Comment: @HvíturFirvaldurPétalePerdue can you provide us with a `var_dump()` of your `$idg` array please.

Comment: `array (size=1)
  0 => string '1' (length=1)`  !  @Jon @Matt

Comment: @HvíturFirvaldurPétalePerdue Follow my answer here to add some error handling. Currently you are only attempting to show an error for the connection not the preparing etc. http://stackoverflow.com/a/37135658/3140646 (also make sure error reporting is set => `error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE)` is a good one to set it too)

Comment: i don't see that this is helping :/ @Matt